# How to remove all elements in String array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to remove all the elements in the `String` array for instance:

```
String example[]={"Apple","Orange","Mango","Grape","Cherry"};
```

Is there any simple to do it,any snippet on it will be helpful.Thanks

Comment: Remove from what? Do you just want to remove from the example[] array? Or do you have another array where you want to remove the elements present in example array?

Comment: remove all the elements .....

Comment: So you want your `String[5]` to be `String[0]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Empty an array in Java / processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208655/empty-an-array-in-java-processing)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If `example` is *not* `final` then a simple reassignment would work:

```
example = new String[example.length];
```

This assumes you need the array to remain the same size. If that's not necessary then create an empty array:

```
example = new String[0];
```

If it *is* `final` then you could `null` out all the elements:

```
Arrays.fill( example, null );
```

- See: [void Arrays#fill(Object[], Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29)
- Consider using an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or similar collection

Comment: First approach(reassignment) should only be preferred if it has to be done once or twice or few times. Otherwise every time you will end up allocating memory for new arrays. Also Second approach can not be used for primitive arrays.

Answer (score 9):

```
example = new String[example.length];
```

If you need dynamic collection, you should consider using one of java.util.Collection implementations that fits your problem. E.g. java.util.List.

Answer (score 4):

Reassign again. Like `example = new String[(size)]`

Answer (score 4):

list.clear() is documented for clearing the ArrayList.

list.removeAll() has no documentation at all in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Usually someone uses collections if something frequently changes.

E.g.

```
    List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // initialize list
    someList.add("Mango");
    someList.add("....");
    // remove all elements
    someList.clear();
    // empty list
```

An `ArrayList` for example uses a backing `Array`. The resizing and this stuff is handled automatically. In most cases this is the appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

Just Re-Initialize the array

`example = new String[size]`

or If it is inside a running loop,Just Re-declare it again,

``` **for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
String example = new String[size]
//Your code goes here``
}** ```