# How to remove all items in table object

Tags: android

I have a table object 'list_animal':

```
Animal[] list_animal = new Animal[3];
list_animal[0] = new Animal(...);
list_animal[1] = new Animal(...);
list_animal[2] = new Animal(...);
```

I want reomve all data in 'list_animal'.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague. If I understand correctly, you can do this:

list_animal = new Animal[3];

Or you can assign NULL to each element.

Answer (score 0):

From here [How to remove all elements in String array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585879/how-to-remove-all-elements-in-string-array-in-java)
You can do this

```
Arrays.fill( list_animal , null );
```